# Is it possible for me to sell my android app on android market using my relative in USA as a proxy?

Tags: google-play

I am an indian resident. Developers in India cant sell android apps on android market. Can anybody enlighten me with any other legal means through which i can sell my apps on android market. 
I have my cousin who is an US citizen, residing in california. Is it possible to sell my app using her as my proxy. Please do ask me if i was not clear enough.

Comment: What does this has got to do with programming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not provide the funds for your relative to open up an Android Market account as a U.S. company and have your relative pay you the funds from a U.S. bank account opened under the company's name? You would basically be developing for this new U.S. mobile software company and getting payed for it. I believe that taxes would be owed to the U.S. government however. You'll need to verify that important aspect.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how much APPROXIMATELY it costs to start a company for this purpose?

Comment: To get a fictitious business name license in my city in California was $35 USD I believe. That's all I needed to get a bank account under a business name. You could always do it under your family member's name though.